# Emit variable not passing array from child to parent?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, eventemitter

I am trying to pass an array of tags from the child component to the parent component using emit. The emit is registering and firing the method in the parent component, but when I log the argument that I passed via emit it returns undefined. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I have passed objects via emit before.

I have tried trying to convert the array to an object, passing it as the this value of the same name without storing it as a variable within the method itself.

```
//edittagsform
<template>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-inputs">
          <h5>Add tags:</h5>
          <tagsField v-on:incoming="updateTagsList()"/><br>
          <h5>Current tags:</h5>
          <div v-if="tags.length > 0">
            <tagsList v-for="tag in tags" v-bind:tag="tag"/>
          </div>
          <div v-else>
            <p>No tags associated</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import tagsField from './tagsField'
import tagsList from './tagsList'

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      tags: {
        tag: this.tagList,
    }
  },
  props: ['tagList'],
  name: 'editTagsForm',
  methods: {
    updateTagsList(newTag) {
      console.log(newTag)
      this.tags.push(newTag)
    }
  },
  components: {
      tagsField,
      tagsList
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

````
//tagsField.vue
<template>
<div class="input-group">
    <form>
        <input-tag v-model="newTags"></input-tag><br>
        <input type="button" value="submit" v-on:click="addTag()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      newTags: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
      addTag() {
          for(var i = 0; i <= this.newTags.length; i++){
              var arr = this.newTags[i]
              this.$emit('incoming', {
                  arr
              })
          }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>```
````

Comment: I am not sure but first of all add: arr = []; into data and than try in your addTag() function inside 'for loop' adding arr.push(). Because up to know nothing is creating your array, and so on array is empty

Comment: Can you try logging “arr” before emitting the event to verify the value is what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//tagsField
<template>
<div class="input-group">
    <form>
        <input-tag v-model="newTags"></input-tag><br>
        <input type="button" value="submit" v-on:click="addTag()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      newTags: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
      addTag() {
        const newTags = this.newTags;
        this.$emit('incoming', newTags)
        this.newTags = []
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

```
//edittagsform
<template>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-inputs">
          <h5>Add tags:</h5>
          <tagsField v-on:incoming="updateTagsList"/><br>
          <h5>Current tags:</h5>
          <div v-if="tags.length > 0">
            <tagsList v-for="tag in tags" v-bind:tag="tag"/>
          </div>
          <div v-else>
            <p>No tags associated</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import tagsField from './tagsField'
import tagsList from './tagsList'

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      tags: this.tagList
    }
  },
  props: ['tagList'],
  name: 'editTagsForm',
  methods: {
    updateTagsList(newTags) {
      console.log(newTags)
      for(var i = 0; i < newTags.length; i++) {
        console.log(i)
        this.tags.push(newTags[i])
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
      tagsField,
      tagsList
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<tagsField v-on:incoming="updateTagsList()"/>
```

Should be

```
<tagsField v-on:incoming="updateTagsList"/>
```

When you have the parentheses, then the method will be called as is, without, it acts as a delegate and the parameters will flow through to the method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Still doesn't solve my problem though.

Comment: I don't downvote, but this answer is actually wrong. Vue is smart enough to detect immediate function calls in `v-on:` bindings and defer their execution until the event occurs.

Comment: Yes, the execution would be deferred, but without any arguments passed to the method.